# creating a scatter plot containing series dynamically using VBA in microsoft excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am rather new to VBA so I would appreciate more thorough explanations of what you did to solve this minor issue.

I am tasked with creating a simple VBA program that takes an already sorted set of data (I learned about it and then used a VBA program to sort my data alphabetically already based on a particular column's values) and does the following two things with it:

1. Graphs a scatter plot with it (either within that sheet or in a separate sheet)

AND

2. Creates series with that scatter plot dynamically (meaning that scatter plot has series on it based on a particular column's value). I will not know how many series I need but I do know that since it's sorted, the column defining the type of data in that row will be in alphabetical order (and I assume the VBA program can first create a series with the first row's name and then not create more series until it finds a different name in that column until it is finished graphing the data)

an example of a simple 3 column table is shown below:

SERIES NAME ___X VALUE_____Y VALUE

A__________________1___________1

A__________________2___________2

A__________________3___________3

A__________________4___________4

B__________________5___________5

B__________________6___________6

B__________________7___________7

C__________________8___________8

C__________________9___________9

C__________________1___________1

(there could be more rows and more unique series names of course... )

so in this example, the graph is already sorted and I would like there to be a scatter plot with 3 series on it (A being the 1st, B being the 2nd, and 3 being the 3rd)

I have the code to create a scatter plot with one series so far but I've been stuck trying to figure this out (code shown below). Any help with explanation  is greatly appreciated :D

Here's my code so far (without the dynamic series part ofc)

```
Sub creatingmyscatterplot()

'Dim aRng As Range
'Dim seriescheck As Range
Dim Chart1 As Chart
Set Chart1 = Charts.Add

'Set aRng = Selection.CurrentRegion
'Set aRng = aRng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(aRng.Rows.Count - 1)
'Set seriescheck = aRng.Resize(aRng.Rows.Count, 1)

'Dim seriesName As String, seriesData As Range
'These lines, as their names suggest, turn off screen refresh and recalculating the workbook's formulas before running the macro.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


With Chart1

    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries

    'This creates the graph
    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet1!$A$2"
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$26001"
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$C$2:$C$26001"


    'Titles
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "X vs. Y"
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "SOME TEXT"
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "SOME TEXT AS WELL"
    .Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True

    'Formatting
    .Axes(xlCategory).HasMinorGridlines = False
    .Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True
    .Axes(xlValue).HasMinorGridlines = False
    .HasLegend = False
    .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 100
    .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0

End With


'These lines, as their names suggest, turn off screen refresh and recalculating the workbook's formulas before running the macro.
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Sorry about the indentation of the first and last lines. I just wanted those lines to be in the code block instead of outside it.

THANKS :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After collect range by your series name, and add series.

```
Sub creatingmyscatterplot()
Dim rngData() As Range, rngDB As Range
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, n As Long

Set Ws = Sheets(1)
    With Ws
        Set rngDB = .Range("a2", .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    'By same value area, set rngData() array
    n = 1
    ReDim Preserve rngData(1 To n) 'dynamic array
    For i = 1 To rngDB.Rows.Count
        If rngData(n) Is Nothing Then
           Set rngData(n) = rngDB(i)
        Else
            Set rngData(n) = Union(rngData(n), rngDB(i))
        End If
        If rngDB(i) <> rngDB(i + 1) Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve rngData(1 To n)
        End If
    Next i

'Dim aRng As Range
'Dim seriescheck As Range
Dim Chart1 As Chart
Set Chart1 = Charts.Add

'Set aRng = Selection.CurrentRegion
'Set aRng = aRng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(aRng.Rows.Count - 1)
'Set seriescheck = aRng.Resize(aRng.Rows.Count, 1)

'Dim seriesName As String, seriesData As Range
'These lines, as their names suggest, turn off screen refresh and recalculating the workbook's formulas before running the macro.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


With Chart1

    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
    'if your activecel in data range, series is created automatically Unintentionally. So,all series are to be deleted
    For i = .SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1
        .SeriesCollection(i).Delete
    Next i
    'This creates the graph
    For i = 1 To n - 1 'useful rngData()'s count is n -1
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(i).Name = rngData(i)(1)
        .SeriesCollection(i).XValues = rngData(i).Offset(, 1)
        .SeriesCollection(i).Values = rngData(i).Offset(, 2)
    Next i

    'Titles
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "X vs. Y"
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "SOME TEXT"
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "SOME TEXT AS WELL"
    .Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True

    'Formatting
    .Axes(xlCategory).HasMinorGridlines = False
    .Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True
    .Axes(xlValue).HasMinorGridlines = False
    .HasLegend = False
    .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 100
    .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0

End With


'These lines, as their names suggest, turn off screen refresh and recalculating the workbook's formulas before running the macro.
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: I was wondering if you could briefly explain this section of code:

Comment: from 
Set Ws = Sheets(1)
to 
Next i

Comment: I meant the block of code containing the dynamic array. I don't quite understand what's going on there and would like a little more information as to what's happening there

Comment: sheets(1) is  data's  sheet. change to your sheet.

Comment: I meant this:

Set Ws = Sheets(1)
    With Ws
        Set rngDB = .Range("a2", .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    'By same value area, set rngData() array
    n = 1
    ReDim Preserve rngData(1 To n) 'dynamic array
    For i = 1 To rngDB.Rows.Count
        If rngData(n) Is Nothing Then
           Set rngData(n) = rngDB(i)
        Else
            Set rngData(n) = Union(rngData(n), rngDB(i))
        End If
        If rngDB(i) <> rngDB(i + 1) Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve rngData(1 To n)
        End If
    Next i

Comment: I know to change the sheet with my sheet. What I don't understand is what that code in particular does and how it execute when I run it. what does it do? how does it work? etc.

Comment: rngData()  as range.   I set dynamic array as range.  And increase array step by step  and your same SERIES NAME range collectted to that. Finally,I have completed the array and applied it to the chart.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I do however have a question: where do you figure out dynamically how many series you have so that you can create the series later on in your code. Is it in that same block of code you are talking about? if so, where?

Comment: Set rngDB = .Range("a2", .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))    your original data range.

Comment: In this range,  I can set dynamic range  rngData()  after code. I don't Konw series count.  but  this code make series according to your data.

Comment: oh ok makes sense now. That's pretty cool. Thanks I understand now :D