# Scatterplot w/ VBA in Excel over multiple worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a macro that will go to each sheet in my workbook, clean up the data (add columns, change units, etc...). After cleaning the data with no issues, I am attempting to create a scatterplot on the worksheet. The code below leaves out the clean up stuff, because it is irrelevant. I have tried a number of iterations including recording macros which was my last attempt. An issue arises from the sheets which were originally from separate excel files. Every sheet has the same format/organization structure, however, they each have a different column length (because the length of data in each varies based on how long the experiment lasted). Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
Sub Cleaning()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each sh In Worksheets

        sh.Activate
        'find column length for loop
        Dim collength As Integer
        collength = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'plot curves
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter).Select
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(ActiveSheet.Name & "!$C$1:$C$" & collength, ActiveSheet.Name & "!$Q$1:$Q$" & collength)

    Next sh

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

In my second attempt, I tried this... Still with no luck.

```
Dim strx As String
Dim stry As String
Dim rngx As Range
Dim rngy As Range

strx = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$C$2:$C$" & collength
stry = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$Q$2:$Q$" & collength

Dim Chart1 As Chart
    Set Chart1 = Charts.Add
    With Chart1
        .ChartType = xlXYScatter
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        'Change to what your series should be called
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Values"""
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=" & rngx
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=" & rngy
    End With
```

On my third attempt, I recorded a macro and edited it to auto-adjust to the active sheet's column length, however, I get a 1004 error on the last line.

```
Sub plotting_test()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each sh In Worksheets
   sh.Activate
'find column length for loop
    Dim collength As Integer
    collength = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   '[B3].Value = collength


    Range("C1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range("B1:B" & collength & ",Q1").Select
    Range("Q1").Activate
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
        ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$1:$B$" & collength & "," & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$Q$1:$Q$" & collength)


Next sh
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46594615/creating-a-scatter-plot-containing-series-dynamically-using-vba-in-microsoft-exc/46596948#46596948)

Answer (score 0):

The following did not generate any errors, and produced a graph based on the data that you've provided:

```
Sub mysub()
Dim sh As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each sh In Worksheets
sh.Activate
'find column length for loop
Dim collength As Integer
collength = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'[B3].Value = collength

Range("C1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range("B1:B" & collength & ",Q1").Select
Range("Q1").Activate
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
sh.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$1:$B$" & collength & "," & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$Q$1:$Q$" & collength)

Next sh
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Which is basically your code anyway, minus the Sub name and Dim sh As Worksheet.

Since you're looping through sh anyway, it makes sense to use that instead of Activesheet. So sh.Name, will give you the current sheet name, but over all, your code works. Can you provide any further information as to what you might be getting which you do not expect, and perhaps a sample of data to try to help further?

Comment: That ended up giving me a number of other errors. No luck this time.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out!
This code goes into each worksheet, cleans up the data and formats it properly, then graphs the desired series.

```
Sub clean_and_graph()

'start with the first sheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each sh In Worksheets
   sh.Activate


'find the collength for the series entry
    Dim collength As Integer
    collength = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'clean up the data
    'Inserting a Column at Column C
        Range("C1").EntireColumn.Insert
        [C1].Value = "time"

        'eqn for first row in column
        [C2].Value = "=if(B2>0,24*(B2-$B$2))"
        'autofill rest of columns and format data to general
        Range("C2:C" & collength).FillDown
        Columns(3).NumberFormat = "General"

    'create the chart as an object in the worksheet
    Dim myChtObj As ChartObject
    Set myChtObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add _
        (Left:=100, Width:=375, Top:=75, Height:=225)
    myChtObj.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range("C2:Q" & collength)
    myChtObj.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines


    With myChtObj.Chart

        ' make an XY chart
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines

        ' remove extra series
        Do Until .SeriesCollection.Count = 0
            .SeriesCollection(1).Delete
        Loop
         With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Name = ActiveSheet.Range("Q1")
        .Values = ActiveSheet.Range("Q2:Q" & collength)
        .XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C" & collength)
        End With
    End With


'go to the next sheet
    Next sh
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```